# Vue.js inputmask hide placeholder after clicking outside input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, input-mask

- Im working on a vue project and i have one component that is a numeric input like so :

```
<template>
   <input
      v-regex="regex"
      type="text"
   />
</template>
```

- the v-regex directive is created with inputmask like so :

```
Vue.directive('regex', {
         bind(element, binding) {
            inputMask({
               regex: binding.value,
               placeholder: '',
               showMaskOnHover: false,
               showMaskOnFocus: false,
               clearMaskOnLostFocus: false,
            }).mask(element)
         },
      })
```

-and the component is used inside a form like this :

```
<myComponent
 id="myId"
 class="my-class"
 :placeholder="'write Number'"
/>
```

**the problem im having is : when i click inside the input and then outside it the placeholder "write Number" disappear and never show again unless i refresh the page , is there a way to fix this ? thank you**

Comment: what happens if you set showMaskOnFocus: true ?

Comment: @FerryKranenburg , Whether i set showMaskOnFocus: true or false , there is no behaviour change , the bug remain. on the other hand showMaskOnHover: false will keep the placeholder on mouseHover , if set to true , the placeholder is hidden on hover .

Comment: See my answer. The placeholder of the inputMask works differently than the placeholder attribute on an input tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `placeholder` property of the inputMask component, [see documentation here](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask). This is different functionality, that placeholder is for digits for example. If you put that placeholder directly on the `<input>` tag it will work like you expect it to work.